# GAE Endpoints gradle build error while generating classes

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, google-cloud-endpoints

Gradle build fails on appengineEndpointsExportClientLibs task with the following stacktrace. I can run the backend module but I can't update any backend classes and see the change.

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskValidationException: A problem was found with the configuration of task ':backend:appengineEndpointsExportClientLibs'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserDataException: No value has been specified for property 'clientLibJarOut'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:47)
    ... 51 more
```